# How to store values in array to plot graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow

I have the following cross entropy function.

```
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))
for i in range(max_training_step):
    batch = next_batch(i)
    if i % FLAGS.beta_resolution == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g" % (i, train_accuracy))
```

I want to print it after every training step. And I want to use `matplotlib` to plot the graph b/w training step and entropy.

How can I do that? (I don't want to use tensorflow for graph plotting)

Answer (score 0):

When you do your session run call (e.g. `res=sess.run(...)` ) then you can put in a fetch for your cross entropy variable.

For example, let's say you have a complicated sess.run() call that gets some predictions but you also want to your cross entropy then you may have code that looks like this:

```

```
feeds={x_data:x,y_data:y}
fetches=[y_result,cross_entropy]
res=sess.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feeds)
predictions=res[0] #your first fetch parameter
xent=res[1] #Your second fetch parameter.
```

```
Fetches within the run call allows you to "fetch" tensors from your graph.

Comment: Can i do it without using tensorflow like this

Comment: if i define training step and cross entropy as empty array and then i store the values in for loop using append command. And then i use matplotlib to plot the graph between two.Can it work in tensor flow code?

Comment: You have to use tensorflow at some point because tensorflow is generating the cross entropy, but if you fetch the cross entropy every run in your for loop then yes, you can append, use with matplotlib or whatever. In the above example cross entropy (xent), which is res[1] above, will just be an array or xent value like any other python variable.